# Skype for Business - Is there any python, bash, nodejs sample available?

Tags: 14.04, bash, python, skype, nodejs

I need to use Skype for business (https://msdn.microsoft.com/skype/websdk/apiproductkeys)  on Ubuntu.

I am looking for working sample or how to get started with it on Ubuntu, but cant get any direction.

Comment: Somewhat related: while writing a Skype bot, the  official documentation was not very helpful: it was incomplete, misleading and just wrong. The code example in JavaScript from a blog post was more helpful for creating a [simple Skype bot in Python (text in Russian)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524924/23044).

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. Here is a link to a blog post for native ways via Pidgin.

http://www.lyncinsider.com/lync-mobile/lync-linux-access-lync-services-linux-computers/

You can also use "Wine" and install the .exe

Personally, I just use the Chrome app.

Comment: Which Chrome app you use? Does it allow you to access the Chrome app status via Javascript? that would be great.